The relativistic Doppler effect is a function of relative velocity. But does the velocity also have to be non-zero relative to the travelling signal?
The classical Doppler effect is a function of that component of the velocities of source and receiver in the direction of the travelling signal. The relativistic Doppler effect is a function of the relative velocity between source and receiver. But in the classical Doppler effect there can be non-zero relative velocity between source and receiver but zero velocity of source and receiver in the direction of the travelling signal, leading to zero Doppler shift. Does the same apply to the relativistic Doppler effect? See below for more detail.
When the signal travels in a straight line from source to receiver, the relative velocity between source and receiver is the same as the velocity relative to the direction of the travelling signal and the question makes no sense, but if the signal is not travelling in a straight line this is not necessarily the case.
This can be seen in the case of a signal travelling around the surface of an expanding balloon, an example of the classical Doppler effect where the signal does not travel in a straight line from source to receiver.
For the classical Doppler effect, the Doppler shift must be determined separately for the source and for the receiver. In this case, the Doppler shift due to the expansion of the balloon is zero because the motions of both source and receiver are perpendicular to that of the travelling signal. There is no motion in the direction of the travelling signal. This is despite there being a relative velocity between the source and the receiver.
Or, you can look at this slightly differently - if you consider the balloon skin to be the medium of transmission there is no motion of neither source nor receiver relative to the medium.
The answer to the question matters a lot. If the answer is yes, then light travelling through a universe with curvature, will, by analogy, experience no Doppler shift due to the expansion of the universe.
I have been asked to clarify the balloon example.The image below shows two rockets a and b. The brown line is a signal passing in a straight line from a to b (you can consider that the launch of b is delayed). To begin with assume the signal is sound in air.There will be a classical Doppler shift at both source and receiver, a function of the velocities of the rockets relative to the direction of the travelling signal (v sin alpha). The yellow and green curves show cases where the signal does not travel in a straight line from source to receptor. Ignore the green line. The velocities of both source and receptor are perpendicular to the direction of the travelling signal (yellow line) so there will be no classical Doppler shift, even though there is relative velocity between source and receiver. It may seem difficult to replicate this experimentally but a signal travelling around the surface of an expanding balloon will do so perfectly.
So the question boils down to this. If the signal is a radio wave, following a curved path, do the same considerations apply - there will be no Doppler shift, or, since the relativistic Doppler effect is only a function of relative velocity is the angle of travel of the rockets, relative to the travelling signal, irrelevant.


I'm having difficulty understanding what you mean by: "the relative velocity between source and receiver is the same as the relative velocity with the travelling signal". What exactly is meant by "relative velocity with the travelling signal"? Note also that for inertial senders & receivers, the speed of light is always constant...

Also, am I right that you've already posted essentially the same question before, from a different account?

I meant that component of the velocity that is in the direction of the travelling signal - not enough space to be explicit. in the question

Covering some of the same ground - but rather different.

Are you essentially asking whether a light signal can approach the receiver with speed less than $c$ due to the expansion?

There is always enough space to explain in the question, the title is a reasonably short and the body is used to explain and give context. So you use the body to expand on the question title.

@amit No not at all. I am discussing the Doppler effect, particularly when the signal is not travelling in a straight line, which is what needs adressing.

@Triatticus. Sorry, I thought it was obvious I was talking about the direction of the travelling signal, not its speed.

You need to be much clearer what setup you are trying to get us to consider. When you brought up the balloon in this question, there was no rhyme nor reason for it to appear. And your question was not understandable even before that.

@ naturallyinconsistent. The balloon is the obvious example of a case where the signal is not travelling in a straight line from source to receiver.

The case that needs considering is when the signal isnot travelling in a straight line from source to receiver.

I love relativistic doppler effect problems--all the principles of relativity come in to play, depending on how you look at it (which is also a principle of relativity)...anyway, after 5 reads I have no idea what is going on in this question. It's just a scrambled mess (which is a feature of a lot of SR questions here). You gotta tighten it up. What's a traveling signal not in a straight line even mean? The Balloon? What? Maybe some diagrams and a concrete description of the not-straight-line traveling signal?

@JohnHobson You already agreed that light always travels at $c$. So how do you think an expression like $v\sin\alpha$ is relevant for a light signal? Assuming as you said you are not asking whether light can slow down due to the relative velocity between the emitter and receiver

@amit. The issue is not the speed of light. That is constant. It is whether the speed of the rockets should be only that component relative to the direction of the travelling signal, as is the case for the classical Doppler effect.

@amit v sin alpha is only applied to the speed of the rockets, not to the speed of the signal.

@JohnHobson Ok, I think your question can be put then as follows: if a stationary (and inertial) observer orients his measurement apparatus in different directions, will he measure different frequencies/wavelengths for the same light signal? Otherwise if that's not what you mean either, I give up :P

@amit. I think the diagram is extremely straightforward, much more so than your statement. But I think the answer to your statement is 'yes' with the proviso that if you were to measure signals arriving from a single source, at different angles they would be traversing different paths and so would  not really be the same signal. So the observer might receive a signal via either the brown or the yellow path. They would show different Doppler shifts. They would be from the same source but I wouldn't call them the same signal.

@amit. And I can't envisage a set up where you could easily choose your path.

@JohnHobson How exactly would they be traversing different paths? You can orient a single detector in different angles, while keeping it at essentially the same point in space. Anyway, you may know that for example diffraction of light waves, which involves light interacting with an obstacle, doesn't change its wavelength. I'm no expert, but I think at least some spectrometers rely on diffraction in order to work. So assuming a monochromatic source, they won't measure a different wavelength if you orient them in different angles.

@JohnHobson What do you mean by velocity relative to a signal? In a non-relativistic case, the measured frequency is simply the frequency at which successive wavefronts reach the detector. As for the relativistic case, you need to consider curved spacetime which is not trivial. For example, light traveling in a gravitational well experiences gravitational redshift/blueshift which is essentially a Doppler effect even though the observers are not moving spatially.

@vincent Thacker. Velocity relative to the direction of the travelling signal. This is the velocity in the classical Doppler effect. In most analyses it is the velocity relative to a straight line drawn between the source and the receiver, but it doesn't have to be.
Gravitational red/blue shift is not relevant here. It is permanent redshift. It remains when the velocity stops. Doppler shift stops when the velocity stops.

@JohnHobson Again, that statement makes no sense as others have already said. What does it mean to specify velocity "relative to the direction"? Velocity is defined relative to a point of reference because it is the time derivative of the displacement from that point of reference.

@Vincent Thacker. I take your point but surely the velocities to use for the classical Doppler effect are the components of the velocities of source and receiver that are in the direction of the travelling signal? That is what I mean. Maybe my use of 'relative' is incorrect.

@JohnHobson Is this what you're looking for?

@amit. This may be relevant for the relativistic Doppler effect but first we have to sort out the classical Doppler effect which doesn't seem to be resolved.

@JohnHobson There are two question marks in your post. Both are questions about the relativistic Doppler effect. So if you meant to ask about the classical Doppler effect, you didn't manage to express that intent in your question apparently.

@amit. The intent was to ask whether the result for a signal travelling around an expanding balloon, no Doppler shift, could be extended to light travelling through curved expanding space. But it is the first part that seems to be causing the problems.

@ Amit. I had seen the link before but thanks for the reminder. I need more time to consider it.

Your statement:

In this case, the Doppler shift due to the expansion of the balloon is zero because the motions of both source and receiver are perpendicular to that of the travelling signal. There is no motion in the direction of the travelling signal. This is despite there being a relative velocity between the source and the receiver.

is not correct. The signal is following a geodesic that is confined to the surface of the balloon, and the distance that matters is the length of this geodesic. If we tie one end of a string to the source and the other end to the receiver and pull the string tight then the length of the geodesic is simply the length of this string, $s$. The velocity that matters when calculating the Doppler shift is the rate of change of the length of the string, $v = ds/dt$, and this is non-zero and therefore the Doppler shift is also non-zero.

Thanks. The first answer. I have been waiting for someone to mention geodesics. But can this be correct. The full formula for the classical Doppler effect makes no mention of relative velocity, only the individual velocities of source and receiver, which must of course be that component of the velocities in the direction of the travelling signal. And in the case of the balloon, this is zero. I think someone needs to carry out the experiment.

But of course your answer may be correct for the relativistic Doppler effect, which is the purpose of the question. The relativistic Doppler effect is a function of relative velocity. But I still suspect the angle the velocity , of source or receiver, makes with the direction of the travelling signal may come into play.

@JohnHobson by restricting the waves to the balloon surface you are converting the problem to waves on a 2D surface. The fact the surface is embedded in a 3D space is irrelevant. Imagine the waves moving along the string connecting the points. If the length of the string changes with time then the number of waves in transit along the string changes with time so the number of waves emitted per second is different from the number of waves emitted per second. You only need consider the length of the string and not any motion in the third dimension.

OK. But there is still no motion of source or receiver in the 2D surface so no Doppler effect at source or receiver. The fact that that the medium is stretching is irrelevant  (it might lead to a frequency shift due to changing tension but that would not be a Doppler shift). The classical Doppler effect requires motion relative to the medium of transmission. There is none here.
I know your's seems to be the majority view but I am certain it is incorrect. As I said, does the experiment need to be performed?

@ John Rennie The number of waves in transit is increasing simply because the length of the string or path is increasing.. This does not mean the number of waves emitted or received per second has to change.

@JohnHobson Yes it does, because the rate of change of the number of waves on the string is the number emitted onto the string per second minus the number received off the string per second. If the number is changing it must means the emission and reception rates are different, i.e. there is a Doppler shift.

Your argument makes no reference to the formula for the classical Doppler effect, but put that to one side.


Yes, the number of waves in transit is increasing, but so is the path length by the same factor so the number of waves per unit pathlength is unchanged, The wavelength is unchanged. No Doppler effect.


And if the number of waves in transit is increasing, your argument would imply an increasing pathlength would lead to an increasing frequency, when the opposite would be the case.



and 3.
I  think your argument falls down because you are assuming a steady state system but of course the system is not steady state.

and 4. 'Yes it does, because the rate of change of the number of waves on the string is the number emitted onto the string per second minus the number received off the string per second. ' This is only true if the length of the string is unchanged. (Perhaps my argument 2. is incorrect but my other points stand. There is no Doppler effect. )
Or yet another way of looking at it. If the frequency is unchanged, the number of waves on the 'string' will increase because it now takes longer for the waves to traverse the string.
